# geom_boxplot not displaying data when I adjust x_axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Very new to R programming and programming in general but I am having trouble displaying my box plots once I adjust my text so that its not all bunched up.

When I run this simple stuff, my boxplot displays the data but obviously, my x_axis labels are too big and run over eachother.

```
    dataFinal <- ggplot(dataFilter, aes(VegClass, REIPWvl))
    dataFinal + geom_boxplot()
```

produces [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB2UL.jpg)

OK, so then I figured out how to adjust the angle of the text so that you can see all the labels, but as soon as I run this the data decides not to display.

```
    dataFinal <- ggplot(dataFilter, aes(VegClass, REIPWvl))
    dataFinal + geom_boxplot()
    dataFinal + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1))
```

[this is the plot I get once I add the last line of code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLF7b.jpg)

Any help would be appreicated, I'm sure I'm missing one small thing or something.

Cheers.

Comment: You need to add the `theme` element after the `geom_boxplot`.  `dataFinal + geom_boxplot() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1))`

Comment: when I do this, then I get an error saying : _Don't know how to add o to a plot_

Comment: wait nevermind, I accidently had and an extra dataFinal + before theme(

Comment: Yes, you assigned `dataFinal <- ggplot(dataFilter, aes(VegClass, REIPWvl))` without the `geom_boxplot()`, therefore you need to add it at each call for it to be plotted.  You can reassign `dataFinal <- ggplot(dataFilter, aes(VegClass, REIPWvl)) + geom_boxplot()`, if you do this then you can call `dataFinal + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1))` by itself.